# How to execute multiple commands from argv with an specific delimiter

Tags: c, fork, exec, command-line-arguments, argv

Recently I had an assignment where I had to make a program that takes from command line two different commands, separated with a '+', for example:

```
ps -lu myUsername + ls -la
```

The objective of the program was to run any two orders simultaneously, with any number of parameters per order, by using `fork()` and `exec()`. This was my solution to this problem:

*Note: the original problem was meant to be run on a machine with Solaris 5.10 and c89 or c99 standard (gcc 3.4.3)*

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <strings.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char delimiter = '+';
    char* auxp; //auxiliar pointer
    int i = 1;
    int position;
    
    while(i < argc){
        if (strcmp("+", argv[i]) == 0) {
            argv[i] = NULL;
            position = i;
        }
        i++;
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(argv[1], &argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (fork() == 0) {
        execvp(argv[position+1], &argv[position+1]);
        exit(1);
    }

    wait(NULL);
    wait(NULL);
    exit(0);
}
```

This was enough for the assignment but I wanted to make it work with **N arguments** instead of only 2. I can't reach a systematic way to find the all the addresses. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advice.

Comment: while `i<argc` . create a temp `char **myargv`. copy each command to myargv , whenever you encounter `+` . fork and execute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case of N commands, need to keep track of where each command starts and ends, and fork a new child whenever the end of a command is found. That could be at a `+` separator argument, or at the end of the original argument list.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
    /*
     * Note: argc could be in range 0 to INT_MAX.
     * Using unsigned int values to avoid arithmetic overflow.
     */
    unsigned int start = 1;
    unsigned int end = 1;
    unsigned int child_count = 0;

    /* Note: argv[argc] is a terminating null pointer. */
    while(end <= (unsigned int)argc){
        if(end == (unsigned int)argc || strcmp("+", argv[end]) == 0){
            /* Reached the terminating null pointer or a command separator. */
            argv[end] = NULL;
            if(start != end){
                /*
                 * Command is not empty.
                 * Fork a child process to execute the command.
                 */
                pid_t child = fork();
                if(child > 0){
                    /* Parent forked child successfully. */
                    child_count++;
                }else if(child == 0){
                    /* This is the child process. Execute command. */
                    execvp(argv[start], &argv[start]);
                    exit(1);
                }
            }
            /* Next command starts after this one. */
            start = end + 1;
        }
        /* Looking for terminating null pointer or command separator. */
        end++;
    }

    /* Wait for the child processes to terminate. */
    while(child_count){
        wait(NULL);
        child_count--;
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

Note: the `argv[end] = NULL;` line could be moved into the `if(child == 0){` `}` block (but before the call to `execvp`) to leave the parent's original argument list intact.

Answer (score 1):

Just move the forking into the loop:

```
int main (int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char** start = ++argv;
    unsigned int n = 0;
    for(; *argv; ++argv) // profiting from argv being null terminated, too...
    {
        if (strcmp("+", *argv) == 0)
        {
            *argv = NULL;
            if (fork() == 0)
            {
                execvp(*start, start);
                exit(1);
            }
            start = argv + 1;
            ++n; // but need to count how many times we actually forked!
        }
    }

    while(n--)
    {
        wait(NULL);
    }
    exit(0);
}
```

OK, I modified iterating a bit, too – pointers are just so much nicer (personal oppinion...).

Note: This is untested code, if you find a bug please fix yourself...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you please explain to me how the iteration with `for(; *argv, argv)` works? I am new to C and I have never seen a for loop like this.

Comment: @sosensio `for` loops contain three expressions where any of can remain empty: `for(;;)` is another way to write an endless loop. So I won't be doing anything for initialisation, then check for `*argv` not being null (just like with `if(x)`: Anything that is not 0 by value is interpreted as `true` – and pointers effectively are addresses to memory and thus just ordinary integral values as well), finally increment `argv` (note: it's `++argv`). This works because of `argv` being null-terminated (i.e. there's a null *pointer* following as last element, just like the null *character* strings).

Comment: Ah, for the case you don't know for loops at all: `for(X; Y; Z)` where `X` initialises the loop, that part is executed exactly once before the loop body is entered and can contain a variable declaration as well, `Y` is the loop test that is checked before *every* loop run if the body should be entered at all and `Z` is a post-operation that is executed every time the loop *has* run, so *after* the loop body. The classic: `for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {...}`. A good [C book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should introduce you to pretty quickly.